# Apache HttpClient skips Authorization header in the next call after getting 401

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, unauthorized

When I do two sequential same HttpGet requests with the wrong authentication data, the first request returns proper 401 error but second does not return the 401 error.

I'm calling HttpGet request with wrong authorization (basic).
The response gives proper 401 error.
Right after I do the second HttpGet to the same url with the same wrong authorization data.
And the second request has no Authorization header (I see that it does not exists when debugging the request processing), so it does not return the 401 response.

It there any way to force the usage of the auth header or clean the failure cache or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with the same problem, i found a solution. Send a custom header with different name like X-Authorization. Put your bearer token in this parameter and send the request.
On the server side, create a middleware and use this custom parameter for authorization instead of default parameter. I have done this in laravel, I sent X-Authorization from postman headers tab and on the laravel side, i made a middleware and used this token to get the user Authorised.

Comment: Muhammad, thank you for your note, but unfortunately I don't control the backend, so need to find how to properly reset the client

Comment: If you are sending header properly, then  your are already doing your job properly.  Server sometime, skips the header parameter due to different reasons. That's not your concern if you don't have server access.